# When trying to remove first object, how can I catch an empty LinkedList exception in Smalltalk?

Tags: exception, linked-list, smalltalk

I'm new at Smalltalk and trying not to use if statements!
On Python I would write:

```
try:
   element = LinkedList.remove()
except:
   element = "nil"
finally:
   return element
```

What is the equivalent in Smalltalk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer:

```
^aLinkedList remove: aLinkOrObject ifAbsent: [nil]
```

Note that in Smalltalk all collections that support the removal of elements also support the `remove:ifAbsent:` message. The first argument is the element to remove and the second a block that would handle the case where the element is not in the collection.

More generally, the way to handle exceptions in Smalltalk follows the pattern:

```
[<Smalltalk expression>] on: Error do: [:ex | <handle ex>]
```

Even more generally, the argument `Error` can be replaced with any subclass of the `Exception` hierarchy, meaning that your code will only handle certain kinds of exceptions.

Exception handling is a broad topic in Smalltalk, so consider this answer as a hint to help you write some preliminary Smalltalk code.

**EDIT**

The answer and comments by @SeanDeNigris made me realize that my answer is incomplete in, at least, one aspect: *how do we determine the first element of the list*? In fact, the expression that uses `remove:ifAbsent:` says nothing about the first argument, which the original question identifies as the first element. To complete the answer we have to resolve also this issue.

In a first attempt we could try:

```
^aLinkedList remove: aLinkedList first ifAbsent: [nil]
```

But the problem is that the message `aLinkedList first` will signal an error if the list happens to be empty. In other words, the `ifAbsent:` part will be useless. So, as Sean suggests, we are left with two alternatives. In the first one we use conditional logic to establish a distinction on whether the list is empty or not:

```
^aLinkedList isEmpty
    ifTrue: [nil]
    ifFalse: [aLinkedList remove: aLinkedList first]
```

The second alternative consists in using exceptions:

```
^[aLinkedList remove: aLinkedList first] on: Error do: [nil]
```

At this point we are faced with the question of which alternative is better. A good criterion to apply is simplicity. Which solution is simpler? Clearly the first one. Error handling is an advanced capability that uses some non-trivial machinery. The first solution relies on elementary conditional logic. Moreover, what's the point of pretending that we cannot anticipate an exception if we know in advance that the only expected error will happen if the list is empty. In this regard the use of exceptions and `on:do:` is overkilling and we should avoid it here.

Comment: +1, though I'd refactor the return that's in the `ifTrue:ifFalse:` blocks, i.e.: `^aLinkedList isEmpty ifTrue: [nil] ifFalse: [aLinkedList remove: aLinkedList first]`. I also agree with @Sean that it would be cleaner to refactor all of that into a separate method, and `#removeFirstUnlessEmpty` is a nice, clear name that will stop the next peson wanting this from reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I also prefer one return outside the blocks. I didn't write it that way because the question was asked by a beginner and factoring the return out is a little bit more advanced. In fact I would have also eliminated the `ifTrue: [nil]` branch (even though that wouldn't conform the ANSI standard.)

Comment: The `ifTrue: [nil]` isn't too bad though as it reveals the intention a bit more explicitly

Answer (score 3):

As Leandro said, the literal answer to your question is to wrap the statement in an `#on:do:` block

But... Unless you're doing this as a kata-like exercise, sometimes it's okay to use "if"! In your Python example, the system seems to be providing you some built-in support, which in Smalltalk might be something like `#removeFirstUnlessEmpty` (which you could implement to hide the ugliness). Once you have to resort to exceptions, I wouldn't say that's better than using if.

If it makes you feel any better, in Smalltalk #ifTrue: is a message, not a statement, so it doesn't affect the purity of your code... unless you nest them, which is just in poor taste ;)

Comment: @SeanDeNegris This is a very good point. Sometimes a simple IF is much better than handling an exception, especially when the code can easily anticipate such an event. Note however that `remove:ifAbsent:` does precisely that in a way that frees the senders of `remove:` from writing the conditional logic in their own terms.

Comment: True re #remove:ifAbsent:, but the use case is #removeFirst, where the suggested approach requires you to know the object in advance, and would remove it even if it was e.g. the 10th item, no?